# In Blazor Server (.net7) how do you grab data from ProtectedLocalStorage?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

My question is how do I grab stored data from the ProtectedLocalStorage. When I attempted to do so I keep getting blank values for the retrieved value (no crashes or error messages) and am able to concatenate the blank string with another string and display it (using login.razor as my test page). How do I grab the value without it being blank? I am mainly focused on getting the user variable to work as if one can be done then I can expand it to however many are needed. Thank you in advance.

_Imports.razor

```
@using System.Net.Http
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.Virtualization
@using Microsoft.JSInterop
@using MongoDB.Bson;
@using MongoDB.Driver;
@using Project
@using Project.Shared
@using Project.Models
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ProtectedBrowserStorage;
```

login.razor

```
@page "/login"
@inject ProtectedLocalStorage storage


<!doctype html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>login</title>

    
</head>
  <body>
      <button @onclick = "@StoreValueAsync">set session data</button>

      <button @onclick = "@removeValueAsync">remove session data</button>

      <button @onclick = "@getValueAsync">get values</button>

      @testString

      
  </body>

@code
{
    private string? testString = "teststring";

    public void StoreValueAsync()
    {
        storage.SetAsync("username", "user");
        storage.SetAsync("password", "pass");
    }

    public void removeValueAsync()
    {
        storage.DeleteAsync("username");
        storage.DeleteAsync("password");
    }

    public void getValueAsync()
    {
        string? user = storage.GetAsync<string>("username").ToString();
        var pass = storage.GetAsync<string>("password");

        if (user != null)
        {
            testString = user + " and user is not null";
        }
        else
        {
            testString = user + "and user is null";
        }

    }


}
```

edit:

images of the site and console not grabbing the username value, the buttons pressed in order prior to screenshots: set session data, get values

[image: site]

[image: console]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Updated answer

Here's my slightly modified version of your page.  If this is a Blazor Page then what is all the header stuff?

It works as I believe it's supposed to:

```cs
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ProtectedBrowserStorage;
@inject ProtectedLocalStorage storage


<div>
    <button @onclick="@StoreValueAsync">set session data</button>

    <button @onclick="@removeValueAsync">remove session data</button>

    <button @onclick="@getValueAsync">get values</button>

</div>

<div class="alert alert-info m-3">
    @testString
</div>


@code
{
    private string? testString = "teststring";

    public void StoreValueAsync()
    {
        storage.SetAsync("username", "fred");
        storage.SetAsync("password", "pass");
    }

    public void removeValueAsync()
    {
        storage.DeleteAsync("username");
        storage.DeleteAsync("password");
    }

    public async Task getValueAsync()
    {
        string? user = null;
        var result = await storage.GetAsync<string>("username");

        if (result.Success)
            user = result.Value;

        if (user != null)
        {
            testString = user + " and user is not null";
        }
        else
        {
            testString = user + "and user is null";
        }
    }
}
```

There's also another question/answer here I answered a few minutes ago showing how to do local storage without any libraries in both Server and WASM. - [How To Grab Data From Protected Local Storage (Blazor Server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75634022/how-to-grab-data-from-protected-local-storage-blazor-server)

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, however this has an error on line 17 ( [Inject] private LocalStorageService _storage { get; set; } = default!; ) and doesn't really explain why the value in my code is grabbed as an empty string when using storage.GetAsync<> or how to fix it.

Comment: See my revised answer.   I'm a bit confused by your inclusion of `<head>` in your Blazor page?  See the reference to another answer that shows to purist/no library way.

Comment: Again thank you for replying, to answer about the head tag it is because I am porting html files from a prior project, lot of html files, haven't cleaned out the head tags yet. They don't seem to impact anything, but maybe I'm wrong there. Additionally the code you applied has the same problem as the code I originally posted, when I press the get value button, it replaces testString with "and user is not null" (without the quotes). It seems to grab the username value as a blank string. It's possible I misunderstand but shouldn't storage.GetAsync<string>("username") get the value from username?

Comment: Apologies, I missed the blaringly obvious:  your `ToString()` hid the problem.  See my revised code.  The `GetAsync` returns a `ProtectedBrowserStorageResult` not the value itself.

Comment: Not a problem, thank you so much for your help, also I took a look after commenting, the other question you linked is the person I am working with, the two of us were sitting there dumbfounded yesterday. I should've realized it wasn't a string, I don't know how we both missed that. ahh well live and learn I suppose. Thank you so much  for the clarification.

Comment: I've learnt the hard way many times that it's good to do a `var x = .....` and check what x is in your dev environment.

Comment: That is a good idea, I will keep that in mind for the future.