# Why I can't get local storage value?

Tags: blazor, local-storage, blazor-jsruntime

I have strange situation. I create service which work with local stroge and use js file for this. I want to use getAsync fucntion.

localStorage.js

```js
function get(key) {
    console.log('getItem')
    return localStorage.getItem(key)
}
```

ILocalStorageService.cs

```cs
public async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string key) where T : class
    {
        var data = await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("get", key);
        Console.Write("getItem");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(data)) 
        { Console.WriteLine("LocalStorageService: token is null"); return null; }
        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(data);
    }
```

I call this function for get autoriaztion token, which I keep in local storage. This token is object, which have 3 fields.
And I call this twice:

First, in autorization on loading page

```
var token = await localStorageService.GetAsync<Token>(nameof(Token));
```

Second, when I want to get field value

```cs
var operatorToken = await localStorageService.GetAsync<Token>(nameof(Token));
Guid operatorID = Guid.Parse(operatorToken.UserID);
Console.WriteLine("Operator is get");
```

Token.cs

```cs
public class Token
{
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string UserSurname { get; set; }
}
```

In first I get this token, all work correctly. But in second I just get nothing, no errors, no values. How can you see, I use some logs and in chrome console I see 2 'getItem'. It means I call local storage twice, how I want. But I haven't "Operator is get" in my console. Also I debug this step by step and when I go `var data = await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("get", key);` debuging just end. Why I not get value in second situatiob and how to fix this?

Comment: see - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75634022/how-to-grab-data-from-protected-local-storage-blazor-server and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75632049/in-blazor-server-net7-how-do-you-grab-data-from-protectedlocalstorage

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis it's not help. I try diffent way to use localStorage. ProtectedLocalStorage from Microsoft, custom localStorage how in question, ```jsRuntime.InvokeAsync("localStorage.getItem)"```. That's all not work. When I want get value from localStorage second time in one page, I can't do this.

Comment: It should work.  WASM or Server?  WASM I suspect.  Check that the token exists in the browser using F12 browser tools.  Also show your Token class and I'll try to add some demo code as a answer.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis It's Blazor Server. LocalStorage have Token field and keep three value, how I want it. It's work correct. Token is simple class, which contain three public field. I add class to question.